# Jmeter test with Apache Wicket

Tags: wicket, jmeter

I've got an application built on Apache Wicket that I want to test with JMeter. But I've got a problem when I submit a form - all fields are empty on the server side. Does anybody test Apache Wicket applications with Jmeter with success?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [these articles](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-and-jmeter.html) could help.

If you need an example that just works, than maybe **click-bench** (a very simple benchmark that compares Wicket, Click and other frameworks) is a good start for you to make your tests working.

You can checkout the [sources for click-bench](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/click/trunk/examples/click-bench/), and see how it's done.